Statistical Approach for Anomaly Detection in Multivariate time series
I'm working on an anomaly detection problem for motor experiments 9same type of motor) and need advice on statistical approaches (No ML since I do no not have enough data). Here's the context:
Dataset:

46 experiments on identical motors
4 phases per experiment, each with a variable number of runs
12 features measured over 35 steps in each run (35x12 data frame per run)
Phases 1-3 on one machine, Phase 4 on a different machine
15 motors labeled 'Operational', 2 'Non-Operational', and the rest is unlabeled

Process:

Phase 1: Motor warm-up (3-5 runs)
Phases 2-3: Mass removal by milling (same process, different planes)(3-11 runs)
Phase 4: Testing on a different machine (no milling) (3-7 runs)
Acoustic test for final classification (details and data not relevant here. Just the classification)

Constraints:

Prefer statistical methods to machine learning due to limited data
Many features are highly correlated across runs and phases

Questions:

What statistical approaches are suitable for anomaly detection in this multiphase process? It is quite messy in my mind, and this is my first anomaly detection project.
Should anomaly detection be performed separately for each phase?
How to handle the variable number of runs in each phase?
Are there specific statistical tests (e.g., A/B testing) that could be valuable here?
What about Isolation Forest, K-Mean, Clustering, PCA, Gaussian Distribution?

As mentioned, I want to detect the anomaly in each feature separately. Ideally, find a correlation between features and deduct that a specific pattern is happening in feature 1 when feature 5 follows a specific pattern. This is my first project on this and considering the huge amount of data it is overwhelming and hard to visualize a right approach. Maybe first reduce the data to 6 features because I am suspecting 4 features to be correlated with the 2 Acceleration features I am having.
Any advice on structuring this analysis or specific statistical techniques to apply would be greatly appreciated (Steps of data pre-processing and structuring, algorithms and statistical methods to be used, etc.)
